# conditionalOnBean not work on beans created via starters

Tags: spring-boot

I have a simple bean called meterUtil and it depends on PrometheusMeterRegistry which is created in actuator starter. so i defined the bean as follow:

```
@ConditionalOnBean(PrometheusMeterRegistry.class)
public MeterUtil meterUtil(PrometheusMeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    return new MeterUtil(meterRegistry);
}
```

but as PrometheusMeterRegistry is created later meterUtil is never created with @ConditionalOnBean. i also tried @DependsOn("prometheusMeterRegistry") and Conditional class as follow:

```
@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    try {
        Map<String, MeterRegistry> beansOfType = context.getBeanFactory().getBeansOfType(MeterRegistry.class);
        if (beansOfType != null && beansOfType.size() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (BeansException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but non work correctly. is there any way to achieve this?
i also wonder if we can depend bean creation on existence of specific dependency in our starter? if dependency classes not exist in our starter. in this example can we depend creation of meterUtil on existence of actuator dependency?
any help is appreciated.